# MySQL CAST function not working and outputted as column name

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a mysql query like this:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
               "
               (SELECT 
                CAST(active AS SIGNED)
                FROM $table_name
                WHERE user_id = %d)
                ", $user_id
        ), ARRAY_A); // Output query as array
```

I then output the result with json_encode, however, the result is outputted like this:

```
{"CAST(active AS SIGNED)":"1"}
```

It shows the function name as column name and the value is still a string.
Any ideas what's going on ? Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: If that worked for you, please mark the answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your SQL adding an "as" statement. Like this:

```
(SELECT 
 CAST(active AS SIGNED) as column
 FROM $table_name
 WHERE user_id = %d)
```

Then you can fetch your data using the name "column".

Comment: Thanks, i tried that and it does fix the column name issue, but the value is still returned as a string.